# Extract values at specific location in string in Python

Tags: python, regex

Given a data stream, how do I extract the information (between `\x15` and `\x15\n`) that comes right after a `*PAR`?

Here is the data stream.

```
'%gra:bla bla bla\n',
'*PAR:\tthe cat wants\n',
'\tcookies . \x159400_14000\x15\n',
'%mor:\tdet:art|the adj|cat\n',
'\tpro:rel|which aux|be&3S part|tip-PRESP coord|and pro:sub|he\n',
'\tv|want-3S n|cookie-PL .\n',
'%gra:\t1|3|DET 2|3|MOD 3|4|SUBJ 4|0|ROOT 5|4|JCT 6|7|DET 7|5|POBJ 8|10|LINK\n',
'\t9|10|AUX 10|7|CMOD 11|13|LINK 12|13|SUBJ 13|10|CJCT 14|13|OBJ 15|16|INF\n',
'\t16|14|XMOD 17|16|JCT 18|19|DET 19|17|POBJ 20|4|PUNCT\n',
'*PAR:\ cookies biscuit\n',
'\tis eating a cookie . \x1514000_18647\x15\n',
```

My output should be:

```
"9400_14000"
"14000_18647"
...
```

Comment: A simple regex will get the work done

Answer (score 1):

Go over the data line by line and try to look for the desired pattern just on lines that follow `*PAR`:

```py
import re
[re.search('\x15(.*)\x15\n', line).groups()[0]
 for i, line in enumerate(data) if '*PAR' in data[i - 1]]
```

This code will throw an exception if the pattern cannot be matched on a line that follows `*PAR`. To get all valid matches use:

```py
[match
 for i, line in enumerate(data) if '*PAR' in data[i - 1]
 for match in re.findall('\x15(.*)\x15\n', line)]
```

If you expect more than a single pair of `\x15` on a line you can use this regex instead to find the shortest match:

```py
'\x15(.*?)\x15\n'
```

Comment: maybe this pattern is more suitable: `r"\x15([^\x15]+)\x15\n"`

Comment: Maybe - depends on what the author can assume about the input data. I don't think the newline can help since the stream is already split into lines

Comment: the new line is part of the question ;)

Comment: Ah, my bad, fixing

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this function

```py
def get_between(string:str,start:str,end:str,with_brackets=True):
    #re.escape escapes all characters that need to be escaped
    new_start=re.escape(start)
    new_end=re.escape(end)
    pattern=f"{new_start}.*?{new_end}"
    res=re.findall(pattern,string)
    if with_brackets:
        return res #-> this is with the brackets
    else:
        return [x[len(start):-len(end)] for x in res]#-> this is without the brackets
```

To use it in your example do this:

```py
result = []
for i,string in enumerate(data_stream):
 if i>0 and "*PAR" in data_stream[i-1]:
  result+=get_between(string,"\x15","\x15\n",False)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the type of the data stream so, here is a generator:

```
def generator(data_stream):
    pattern = r"\x15([^\x15]+)\x15\n"
    search_next=False
    for line in data_stream:
        if search_next:
            for out in re.findall(pattern, line):
                yield out
            search_next = False
        if line.find("*PAR") > -1:
            search_next = True
```

If it can be converted to a list, you can use this:

```
[x for x in generator(data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the newer `regex` module with

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\*PAR)        # fast forward to *PAR
(?:(?!:\*PAR).)+?\\x15\K  # do not overrun another *PAR, fast forward to \x15
.+?                       # start matching...
(?=\\x15|\z)              # ... up to either \x15 or the end
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uwDvGl/1) (and mind the `singleline` and `verbose` modifier!).